# Updating a codable user struct

Tags: swift, codable

I'm developing an app where the user can create up to 5 profiles when I came across a problem.

**Problem:**

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

**Info:**

The first edition of the app has a struct with these data points in it:

- id
- profileName
- profileIcon

When the app opens it loads the user via `func loadUser()`

Now, during an update I've added a new data point in the user struct so it now looks like this:

- id
- profileName
- profileIcon
- profileSummary

Now when the `func loadUser()` is called it fails with this statement:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

**How the system is built:**
When the app is opened the first time it creates 5 empty profiles. The user can then "activate" and fill out these profiles and he/she likes.

**I'm a little uncertain how to deal with this problem. How can I add new data points to my struct without causing the app to crash?**

**Source code:**

```
struct User: Codable {
  // Core user data
  let id:                     Int
  var profileName:            String
  var profileIcon:            String
  var profileSummary:         String
}

class DataManager: NSObject {

/// Used to encode and save user to UserDefaults
func saveUser(_ user: User) {

   if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "userProfile_\(user.id)")
        print("Saved user (ID: \(user.id)) successfully.")
   }

}

/// Used to decode and load user from UserDefaults
func loadUser(_ userID: Int) -> User {
    var user : User?

    if let userData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "userProfile_\(userID)"),
        let userFile = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: userData) {
        user = userFile
        print("Loaded user (ID: \(user!.id)) successfully.")
    }

    return user!
}

 /// Used to create x empty userprofiles ready to be used
func createEmptyProfiles() {
    // May be changed, but remember to adjust UI
    var profilesAllowed = 5

    while profilesAllowed != 0 {
        print("Attempting to create empty profile for user with ID \(profilesAllowed)")

        let user = User(id: profilesAllowed, profileName: "", profileIcon: "", profileSummary: "Write a bit about your profile here..")

        self.saveUser(user)

        print("User with ID \(profilesAllowed) was created and saved successfully")

        // Substract one
        profilesAllowed -= 1
    }
}

 //MARK: - Delete profile
func deleteUser(user: User) -> Bool {

    var userHasBeenDeleted = false
    var userToDelete = user

    // Reset all values
    userToDelete.profileName = ""
    userToDelete.profileIcon = ""
    userToDelete.profileSummary = ""

    // Save the resetted user
    if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(userToDelete) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "userProfile_\(user.id)")
        print("User has now been deleted")
        userHasBeenDeleted = true
    }

    return userHasBeenDeleted

  }
}
```

Comment: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file" in this example means one of your `User` properties doesn't exist in your JSON file. Could you share the JSON input?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Make `profileSummary` optional

   ```
   struct User: Codable {
     // Core user data
     let id:                     Int
     var profileName:            String
     var profileIcon:            String
     var profileSummary:         String?
   }
   ```

   If the key doesn't exist it will be ignored.
2. Implement `init(from decoder)` and decode `profileSummary` with `decodeIfPresent` assigning an empty string if it isn't.

Side note:

**Never** `try?` in a `Codable` context. Catch the error and handle it. Your `loadUser` method crashes reliably if an error occurs. A safe way is to make the method `throw` and hand over errors to the caller.

```
enum ProfileError : Error { case profileNotAvailable }

/// Used to decode and load user from UserDefaults
func loadUser(_ userID: Int) throws -> User {          
    guard let userData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "userProfile_\(userID)") else { throw ProfileError.profileNotAvailable }
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: userData)
}
```